# how to design Guest posting system for cooking related Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to make a Guest posting system in ASP.NET MVC for a cooking website. i want to make it without flash or less use of Flash.

i want to make them upon pure jQuery so i used ajax uploading of images [for without refresh see them]

i see a sample online http://allrecipes.co.in/cooks/my-stuff/submit-a-recipe.aspx but i need to make much better then it and i want to make them without flash using jQuery.

can someone show me what thing i need to use or any suggestion how i can make it on javascript.

any example or suggestion help me to do this

username  :anirudha
password :password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image upload you may see this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/03/image-preview-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). There are many jquery plugins available such as jquery drag drop qtip but you should decide yourself and decide which suits you requirements best